# Query data from table using reader

Tags: c#

Currently I try retrieve data of a register of a table but it doesn't retrieve anything, Any idea?. I don't know if my script is wrong or i'm missing something. don't Capture nothing. Also i try with this query but i don't know if the Where is the correct form? SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select clase, operacion from Clase_Documento where codigoafip = '"+ codafip +"' ", conn);

```
Field codafip = (Field)doc.Fields["ZIMCodigoAFIP"];
Field clasedoc = (Field)doc.Fields["ZIMBlart"];
Field operacion = (Field)doc.Fields["ZIMOperacion"];

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\DOKUSTAR;Database=RdaDB10;User ID=bcc;Password=******;Trusted_Connection=Yes";
conn.Open();

SqlDataReader dr;
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from Clase_Documento", conn);
dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
    if (codafip.Value == dr.GetString(4))
    {   
        string clasedoc2 = dr.GetString(1);
        string operacion2 = dr.GetString(5);
        clasedoc.Value = clasedoc2; //here put the data of the table in its respective field
        operacion.Value = operacion2; //here put the data of the table in its respective field
    }
}
```

Only to clarify, mi table is this, and the field that I want retrieve is "clase" and "operacion" depending of parameter codigoafip
[image]

Comment: How do you know it doesn't retrieve anything? Maybe the condition isn't met.

Comment: you need some where to store your result, List<Clase_Documento> for example

Comment: Why do you select all the data from the table instead of using a `where` clause with `codafip.Value`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you select only the fields you need with a where clause for the match? And what is the purpose of while loop? In affect you are trying to get the last matching row's value, use a LIMIT or TOP clause depending on your backend (or easier use LInq) - TOP, your backend was MS SQL.

Comment: @CetinBasoz good point, I had not thought of it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your field names were claseDocField, operacionField and codafipField (and all string):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\DOKUSTAR;Database=RdaDB10;Trusted_Connection=Yes"))
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(@"select top(1) clasedocField, operacionField
from Clase_Documento
where codafipField = @codafip", conn))
{
 comm.Parameters.Add("@codafip", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codafip.Value;
 conn.Open();

  SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
  if(dr.Read())
  {
        clasedoc.Value = (string)dr["claseDocField"];
        operacion.Value = (string)dr["operacionField"];
  }
}
```

EDIT:

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\DOKUSTAR;Database=RdaDB10;Trusted_Connection=Yes"))
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(@"select top(1) clase, operacion
    from Clase_Documento
    where codigoafip = @codafip", conn))
    {
     comm.Parameters.Add("@codafip", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codafip
;
     conn.Open();

      SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
      if(dr.Read())
      {
            clasedoc.Value = (string)dr["clase"];
            operacion.Value = (string)dr["operacion"];
      }
      else 
      {
           clasedoc.Value = "Not found";
      }
    }
```

Comment: at the moment of compilate it tell me an error: "SqlDbType does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @ObedSilva, then you could write System.Data.SqlDbType.

Comment: still don't wroks

Comment: @ObedSilva, what do you mean. What is the error message? Maybe there isn't a match to your search. Did you try With correct field names?

Comment: @ObedSilva I don't see where your fields are ("the end of this post"?)

Comment: Hello, I update my question, I working with my code but still don't working :(

Comment: @ObedSilva OK edited based on your given field names. Remember for it to work there should be a match. If it doesn't debug.